# LibGit2Sharp Clone fails with LibGit2SharpException: Failed to mmap

Tags: libgit2sharp

Trying to clone a remote repository using LibGit2Sharp v.0.18.1.0 throws this exception:

> LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException: Failed to mmap. Invalid handle value: The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.ZeroResult(Int32 result)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions& opts)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, CloneOptions options)

Using the same url and workdir, I have successfully cloned the repository both using Git Bash and SourceTree. But for my task I need to do it programatically, and LibGit2Sharp seemed like a good choice.

Update: Somehow the error changed, now I get around 20KB of the remote repository and then this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in LibGit2Sharp.dll
>
> Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Update 2: The AccessViolationException was caused by a different cause (trying to clone with an emtpy   string as remote url!)

Comment: Please file an issue in the **[issue tracker](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/new)**. We'll happily take a look at it.

Comment: @kayak58 I am facing almost exactly the same error as you are when running the GitVersion application against my repository which is stored in Stash.  Unfortunately, my repo is private, and I can't share it with the public.  Is it possible that your repo is public?  That way the maintainers of LibGit2Sharp might be able to take a look and see what is going on?

Comment: Issue created: [#794](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/794)

Comment: @Gary: Unfortunately I'm accessing a private repo on Stash as well, but I might convince the owners to make public repo for test.

Comment: @kayak58, if you could that would be great. I unfortunately don't have that luxury :-( Interesting that we are both running Stash. Which version of Stash are you using?

Comment: nulltoken has created a temporary fix for this problem: [https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/794#issuecomment-52778189](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/794#issuecomment-52778189)

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

This is an issue with LibGit2Sharp v0.18.1. This will be fixed in the upcoming v0.19 (See PR **[#798](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/798)**).

**More detailed information**

It looks like Stash sends empty packets to keep the connection alive while the repository is being fetched. The embedded version of libgit2 in LibGit2Sharp v0.18.1 was thus trying to map a zero length file, causing the error.

It's been fixed meanwhile in libgit2 with commit **[libgit2/libgit2@bc8a08868](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/bc8a08868)**.

### Update

The Pull Request has been merged and the issue is fixed in the now released LibGit2Sharp v0.19. This issue should no longer happen.